# SharePoint 2013 Enterprise Wiki - how to create new page to specific path?

Tags: wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

On our SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm, I have created an Enterprise Wiki.
By default all the wiki pages are created under `/Pages/` library. Under the libraries I created some folders (i.e. `/Pages/Animal/` , `/Pages/Plant/`). Under those folder I created a wiki page (e.g. `/Pages/Animal/index.aspx`)

On the `index.aspx` page content area I typed in `[[Dog]]` and save the page. I click on the "Dog" link with dotted underline, SharePoint asked whether I want to create `dog.aspx`.

However it doesn't let me choose the path. End up all the new wiki pages are created at `/Pages/` root (i.e. `/Pages/Dog.aspx`)

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

To create wiki page at specific path, instead of [[Dog]], I need to type [[Animal/Dog|Dog]]. The end result will be a dotted link "Dog". When click on it and create a new page it will be created under /Animal/ folder.